# task of validating that all elements in the input array are strictly positive (Python)

Tags: python

Your assistance is required to verify that every single element in the input array exudes positivity. Your task is to scrutinize the code with precision and guarantee that this requirement is met without compromise. Failure is not an option, and your swift and accurate assessment is crucial to our success. Dive into the code with unwavering determination and exhibit your expertise in ensuring that all elements shine brightly in their positivity. Show me you have what it takes.

Nothing and its all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my friend, it's so easy:

```
def task_1(arr):
    return all(x > 0 for x in arr)
print(task_1([-1, -2, -3])) 
print(task_1([1, 2, 1]))  
print(task_1([-1, 1, 2]))
```

Have a good mark :)

Comment: omg guy, thank you very much. I don't think how easy it was!